# Check if an argument is a dotted pair and not a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I've just started learning Racket and I have to check if an argument is a dotted pair.

I have tried this:

```
(pair? '(a . 1))
```

And returns `#t`.

```
(pair? '('(a b c) . 1))
```

And returns `#t`.

```
(pair? '(a b c))
```

And returns `#t`. But I want to get #f in this case.

Is there another procedure like `pair?` to get true only when I pass it as argument a dotted pair?

Maybe I will have to implement a procedure that check if it is not a list before I check if it is a pair.

**UPDATE**
I only need to check that `'(a . 1)` is a dotted pair and any list is not a dotted pair.

Comment: `(not (list? lst))` should do it

Comment: @leppie But that would return #t for `'(1 2 . 3)` as well. I believe the author is looking for dotted pairs only.

Comment: @merlyn But `(1 2 . 3)` is `(1 . (2 . 3))`, a dotted pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are pedantic a dotted pair is nothing more than a notation, a way to write a pair. The expression `’(a . d)` evaluates to value namely a cons cell.

When a function is applied to some arguments, the arguments are values. This means that a function can not receive a dotted pair - it can receive a cons cell.

Okay - but can a function know whether a value is a cons cell or a list? Depends on what you mean. A list is represented as either null (the empty list) or as a cons cell, whose second element is a list.

The predicate `pair?` will therefore return true for all lists (except the empty list).
Now we can check that a cons cell is not the first cons cells of a list  by writing `(and (pair? x) (not (list? x)))`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a built-in function to filter dotted pairs. But implementing one should be simple. Just check if the argument is a list with more than one element and that `cdr` of the list is not a pair itself.

Here's a sample implementation.

```
(define (not-list-dotted-pair? x)
  (and
    (pair? x)
    (not (null? (cdr x)))
    (not (pair? (cdr x)))))
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and the only problem I have with it is the name of the predicate: lists *are* by nature dotted-pairs, but giving a list to the predicate returns false. Maybe `atomic-dotted-pair?`, `non-list-dotted-pair?`, something else?